# Using \newcommand with ellipse in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I want to use some constants, height and width, when creating an `ellipse` but it won't work with `\newcommand`. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, trees, positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 

    \newcommand*{\width}{2}%
    \newcommand*{\height}{0.5*\width}%

    \draw[fill=gray!40] (0, 0) ellipse (\width and \height); \node (Y) at (0,0) {\(Y\)};    

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

error: line 14:

```
Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `a' or `an' (in '2and 0.5*2'). ...ay!40] (0,0) ellipse (\width and \height)
```

Comment: The correct usage for the `ellipse` and the `circle` path operator (they're the same in that regard) is: `\draw[fill=gray!40] (0, 0) ellipse[x radius=\width, y radius=.5*\height];` This also makes it possible to use with styles and make reference (e.g. `…[y radius=.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/x radius}] … ellipse[x radius=2] … ellipse[x radius=4] …`). Also, check out the `ellipse` shape from the `shapes.geometric` library. (Your node usages indicates you could use that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `\width` inside braces. The space after `\width` is swallowed to give `2and` which should be `2 and`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, trees, positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \newcommand*{\width}{2}%
    \newcommand*{\height}{0.5*\width}%

    \draw[fill=gray!40] (0, 0) ellipse ({\width} and {\height}); \node (Y) at (0,0) {\(Y\)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, you can also use

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\width}{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\height}{0.5*\width}
```